# ScalaIDE: how do I get tooltips as in Java when hovering over an error?

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

When ScalaIDE detects an error in the source code, it underlines it the same way the JDT does. However, to view the error message, I have to move the mouse over the red icon that's on the left of the line number. And to choose a quickfix I have to press Ctrl+1 while the cursor is on the error.

In JDT I can just hover over the error and it shows me the error message plus all possible fixes.

Is it possible to activate that functionality for Scala somewhere? I didn't find anything in the settings.

This is on Eclipse 4.2 and ScalaIDE 2.1.0 M3.

Comment: You should open a ticket to request this: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets

Comment: @huitseeker: [I've done that](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1001494). Apparently, one can press F2 to get the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is irritating.

I have the **Problems tab** visible as standard and you error will be printed there as well so you can see it directly without hovering.

To enable the tab: Windows -> show view -> Problems

Comment: Thank you, that helps. So, the answer to my question is no, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure, however I don't know any way unfortunately